# Java search String then duplicate and replace

Tags: java, string, search, replace, duplicates

(Absolute beginner here) So I have a list that looks like this:

```
XX5.9
XX5.10
XY5.9
XY5.10
```

My plan is a small program that searches for `5.9` (as a String. All of them are.), duplicates it and places it above. Then changes it to `5.8`. Like this:

```
XX5.8 <-- New
XX5.9
XX5.10
XY5.8 <--New
XY5.9
XY5.10
```

How would I need to do that in Java? (I don't have any code right now)

Comment: Please try to do this yourself and then post your code. This is a community that would love to help you, but not do your work for you.

Comment: The actual problem is that there are too many possible solutions. Why don't you get started first, write your program that reads your list of Strings (from a file, userinput or webserver ...), holds it in a variable (a single String, an array of Strings, a list....) and then calls the method that changes the searchString. Then we can see if the search string is dynamic or static (like always 5.9) and then (**and only then**) this community can provide actual helpful answers to your problem.

Comment: Do you mean you have a `List<String>` or is it a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input you showed us be stored in a regular Java string, you could try the following regex replacement:

```
String input = "XX5.9\nXX5.10\nXY5.9\nXY5.10";
System.out.println(input + "\n");
String output = input.replaceAll("\\b([A-Z]+)5\\.9\\b", "$15.8\n$15.9");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
XX5.9
XX5.10
XY5.9
XY5.10

XX5.8
XX5.9
XX5.10
XY5.8
XY5.9
XY5.10
```

Answer (score 0):

it's always better to put the solutions you tried so we can help you.

For the problem, i would write something like below :

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("XX5.9", "XX5.10", "XY5.9", "XY5.10");

        strings.stream().flatMap(x -> {
            if (x.contains("5.9")) {
                return Stream.of(x.replaceFirst("5.9", "5.8"), x);
            } else {
                return Stream.of(x);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList())
         .forEach(System.out::println); // this is for debug purpose
```